# php mysql not deleting from database

Tags: php, mysql

For some reason this is not deleting anything
now I echo out the $mailers variable, it puts out a email

```
$mailers = $_GET['leaveme'];
    $sql = "DELETE FROM `List` WHERE `email` = '" .$mailers . "'";
    $results = mysql_query($sql, $link) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: What would `exit( $sql );` before the actual execution of the statement show? Does it look correct?

Comment: die(mysql_error()) giving anything?

Comment: Does your user have the rights to delete data from the database? Is there a email named 'leaveme'?

Comment: Do you get an error?

Comment: Note: Use placeholders, don't assamble sql-strings with interpolation!

Comment: @TomRegner to do that he'd have to stop using the deprecated `mysql_*` library first... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Comment: Echo `$sql` and try make that query in phpmyadmin (or whatever else you use). Then show us error you are getting.

Comment: 1) This code is obsolete already 2) it's vulnerable to SQL injection attacks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php and 3) are you actually connecting to the database in the first place?

Comment: Figured it out, thanks so much everyone.

Comment: I don't actually understand the question..? Could you edit the original post to make clearer in what case it did delete records, what change you made and what is happening now in the problem case? Or, if you've figured it out already and it's not something that could be made appropriate to any other users, remove the post?

Comment: my problem was it was putting an extra line in the mysql database

I fixed it with the following

$string = trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', '', $string));

Comment: you need to refactor to NOT use mysql, its a deprecated driver. Use mysqli instead

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you establish your connection correctly inside your `$link` variable.

```
$link = mysql_connect('Host', 'username', 'password'); /* REPLACE NECESSARY DATA */
if (!$link) {
    die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db('database', $link); /* REPLACE NECESSARY DATABASE NAME */
if (!$db_selected) {
    die ('Can\'t use foo : ' . mysql_error());
}
```

Make sure also that your *table* (`Link`) and *column* (`email`) names were correct. Try running it first in your SQL page in PhpMyAdmin.

Take a look at [SQL injections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) and use [`*_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).

```
$mailers = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['leaveme']);
```

But if I were you, you should use [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) instead as `mysql_*` is already [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php).

```
$link = new mysqli("host", "User", "password", "database"); /* REPLACE NECESSARY DATA */

/* CHECK CONNECTION */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

if($stmt = $con->prepare("DELETE FROM List WHERE `email` = ?")){ /* PREPARE THE QUERY */
  $stmt->bind_param("s", $_GET["leaveme"]); /* BIND THIS VARIABLE TO YOUR QUERY */
  $stmt->execute(); /* EXECUTE THE QUERY */
  $stmt->close(); /* CLOSE THE STATEMENT */
} /* END OF PREPARED STATEMENT */
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to connect to the mysql server with mysql_connect and select the DB before calling mysql_query

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass');
if (!$link) die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());

mysql_select_db('yourdbname', $link);

$mailers = $_GET['leaveme'];
$sql = "DELETE FROM `List` WHERE `email` = '" .$mailers . "'";
$results = mysql_query($sql, $link) or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

my problem was it was putting an extra line in the mysql database I fixed it with the following

```
$string = trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', '', $string));
```

Comment: That `trim` function is unnecesary. It only removes whitespaces from start and end of the given string but you've already done that by `preg_replace`.

Comment: Doesn't your database have rows and columns? Where does a line go?